# Why do lidR and LAStools report different point densities?

Tags: lidr, density, lastools

Why do `lidR` and `LAStools` report different point densities?

For a .las that I have here. Both report number of points correctly at 12500 pts.

The CRS is set and both also report it correctly.

But for point density:

- lidR 293.92 points/m²
- LAStools 209.05 points/m²

Why and which one is correct?

As requested, here's a picture of the cloud.

[image]

Comment: Please show a plot of your point cloud

Comment: @JRR Can you explain why?

Comment: To give you a valid and detailed answer. Otherwise I'll have to make guesses on the shape of the point-cloud

Comment: @JRR This picture is fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your point cloud is likely to have a shape that is complex and not square, rectangular or convex (hard to say in your image). Below a point-cloud of mine seen from above.

[image: screenshot]

I don't know how `lastools` estimate the density (we must dig in the source code to know) but in all case it is an estimate and many results are valid depending on how you compute the area covered by the point cloud.

In the above point-cloud we can estimate the density with:

1. The number of points divided by the area of the bounding box. This is inaccurate if the point cloud is not rectangular

   ```r
   density(las@header)
   #> [1] 1.74
   ```
2. To be more accurate `lidR` computes the convex hull of the point cloud and uses the area of this polygon as denumerator.

   ```r
   density(las)
   #> [1] 2.71
   ```
3. To be more accurate we can use a concave hull. lidR does not do that by default because it is computationally demanding but I can do it with internal tools. In this case I get `3.21`
4. We can also use a raster-based approach by rasterizing the density and computing the average

   ```r
   d = grid_density(las)
   mean(d[d>0])
   #> [1] 3.13
   ```
5. With `lastools`, for my point-cloud I get `3.18`.

The points 3,4 and 5 are relatively close so we can suppose that the method in `lastools` is somehow based on the computation of complex hulls or on a raster-based method.

---

**Edit** based on `lasinfo` [source code](https://github.com/LAStools/LAStools/blob/fae36a43f99d6a6c555f7bf651fbcd474946d185/src/lasinfo.cpp#L4146) I was able to reproduce `lastools` output with `lidR`

```r
d = grid_density(las, 2)
> mean(d[d>0])
[1] 3.18
```

Which is a solution that does not work for low density point cloud or longlat point-clouds

Comment: `lasinfo mylas.las -compute_density`.

Comment: Also, `density(tls@header)` gives 227.2283, which is not the same as what `lasinfo` gives. Though closer to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not aware, how these differences will translate to practical computations, but there are some domains where point density is a critical parameter and thus such large differences should be non-tolerable. OTOH it may seem that matching what LAStools produces might be thought as the "grand references", since LAStools is quite broadly used(?)

Comment: Based on https://github.com/LAStools/LAStools/blob/fae36a43f99d6a6c555f7bf651fbcd474946d185/src/lasinfo.cpp#L4146 `lastools` clearly uses a grid-based approach

Comment: See my edit, after digging in lastools source code

Comment: What do you mean by "internal tools"? Some proprietary company-specific tool?

Comment: Internal functions that are not exported to user in `lidR` (but that will be in next version). That being said I'll change the way the density is computed to get something closer to lastools.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I'm about to produce a function to lidR which uses this. And it'd be odd to be non-standards compliant in some sense.

Comment: Can you show me a document supported by an authority that defines a standard way to compute the density of a point cloud?

Comment: I tried the last option with the same file for which the LAStools result is mentioned in the question. For this the last option you give gives 195.9844. Close, but not exactly. Why? If it was supposed to be the same method.

Comment: Based on this: https://groups.google.com/g/lastools/c/2jnKOmWRdwY. The LAStools method may also be approximated by knowing point spacing. Actually for my file of s=0.07 I get d=204.0816, which is much better. Yet still not, surprisingly, exactly what LAStools reports.

Comment: Also, as the lidR developer, what method would you suggest using in general?

Comment: According to the link, lastools uses last returns. I'm using all returns. Maybe `d <- grid_density(filter_last(las), 2)`

Comment: That gives the exact same result as `grid_density(las, 2)` in this case.